# Rust remove one instance of a value from a BinaryHeap

Tags: rust, binary-heap

Looking at the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BinaryHeap.html#) for a Rust `std::collections::BinaryHeap`, I don't see any obvious API for removing a single instance of a value from the collection.

Since BinaryHeaps are essentially Sets with support for multiple values, this is, perhaps, a slightly unusual thing to want to do.

But there also doesn't appear to be any way around this, for example there appears to be no way to count the number of elements of a particular value.

It is possible to remove all instances of a single value with `retain`. However, since I can't tell how many are removed, I can't re-add "N - 1" of them.

The only solution I can think of using the available API is to drain the whole contents and insert all the values, except one, into a new Binary Heap, such that a single value is removed.

If the Binary Heap contains `[a, b, c, c, c, c, d, e]`, I want a way to remove 1 instance of `c`.

Comment: Sounds like this might be better modeled by a `BTreeMap<T, usize>`, where removing an element means decrementing the value.

Comment: @BallpointBen yes I agree having given it some consideration

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I think your assessment is largely correct. So assuming your dataset is such that draining, removing, and re-inserting is not feasible, you probably want to consider other data structures.

BallpointBen's suggestion of `BTreeMap<T, usize>` can be a good option, particularly if you don't need direct priority queue methods.

Other options include [priority-queue](https://crates.io/crates/priority-queue) and [slab](https://crates.io/crates/slab).

You can also consider creating your own data structure, such as a combination of a `BinaryHeap` and a `HashMap`.

Comment: I was going to do `BTreeSet<Vec>` but obviously that's dumb - `BTreeMap<X, usize>` much better, thanks

Comment: Btw, to add context to your suggestions about Priority Queue and Slab. Having done a search, correct me if I am wrong, Slab is something to do with allocating blocks of memory to allow faster malloc/free behavior rather than requiring a call to the host OS. It is a way to increase the performance of memory management in applications which require a large rate of dynamic allocations. Essentially, a memory pool.

Comment: So I am not sure exactly how it is intended to be used by presumably it can be combined with something like a data structure for more effective memory performance.

Comment: Regarding Priority Queue, it seems that this implementation does not permit duplicate entries. If my memory serves me correctly, all implementations in general are the same, and Priority Queues in general require element uniqueness. (No duplicates.)

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant basic priority queues are implemented as binary heaps, so there is fundamentally no difference between the two besides the API. Indeed, the crate `priority-queue` is backed by a heap. However, there are *tons* of other approaches to priority queues, not all of which require uniqueness. But I have to admit I fail to see why you would use a priority queue here instead of a map (may it be backed by a `BTreeMap`, a `HashMap` or whatever you like).

Answer (score 0):

I think this function does what you want:

```rs
fn remove_single_item<T: Ord>(heap: &mut BinaryHeap<T>, item: &T) {
    let mut was_removed = false;
    heap.retain(|it| {
        let should_remove = !was_removed && it == item;
        if should_remove {
            was_removed = true;
        }
        !should_remove
    });
}
```

Example usage:

```rs
let mut heap = BinaryHeap::from([1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 2, 4]);

eprintln!("{heap:?}");
remove_single_item(&mut heap, &2);
eprintln!("{heap:?}");

// [4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1]
// [4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1]
```

Comment: While this is indeed a solution, it runs in `O(N)` time, which makes using a logarithmic data-structure a bit pointless

Comment: Binary heaps are designed to provide efficient insert, peek, and pop (and possibly replace aka pop + insert), removing an arbitrary heap value is not really part of their standard use cases. So it makes sense that the complexity shoots up for that case, in the same way iterating a hashmap in ascending key order is not O(n).